# How to upload files with php the right way?

Tags: php, html

So I have been working on this school project for about a week now and then came across an instance where I had to implement a user registration form where it is supposed to submit the user info as well as the user profile image whose path is to be stored in the DB as well. The drawback is I can't seem to get the upload script working. I have watched tens of tutorials and read like 15 solutions to similar problems from this very platform but still to no avail. I have also made sure that the `php.ini` file has the `file_upload` setting turned on.

HERE IS MY HTML FORM

```
<form style="padding: 1em;" class="ui form small inverted raised segment" action="signup.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                   <h4 class="ui dividing header">Background Information</h4>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="three fields">
                            <div class="field">
                               <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Firstname" required> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <input type="text" name="mname" placeholder="Other name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Lastname" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="two fields">
                            <div class="field">
                              <select name="gender">
                                  <option value="">Select Gender</option>
                                  <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                  <option value="Female">Female</option>
                                  <option value="Other">Other</option>
                              </select>                              
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <input type="date" name="dob" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui dividing header">Contact Information</div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="two fields">
                          <div class="field">
                            <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Mobile phone number" required>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="field">
                            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" required/>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="three fields">
                            <div class="field">
                              <input type="text" name="area" placeholder="Area/Village" required>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <input type="text" name="trad_auth" placeholder="T/A or STA">
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                              <select id="district" name="kasungu">
                                  <option value="Kasungu">Kasungu</option>
                              </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui dividing header">Work Details</div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <div class="two field">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <select id="department" name="department">
                                        <option value="">Select Department</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui dividing header">Acc Authentication Details</div>
                        <div class="field">
                          <input type="text" name="activation-code" placeholder="Enter admin authentication code (XXX-XXXX-XXXX)" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                          <div class="two fields">
                            <div class="field">
                              <input type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="Create Password" required/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                              <input type="password" name="pass2" placeholder="Confirm Password" required/>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui dividing header">Upload Image</div>
                        <div class="field">
                          <div class="two fields">
                            <div class="field">
                               <input type="file" style="display: none;" id="pic" name="image"/>
                              <a type="button" id="upload" class="ui button fluid negative mini"><i class="icon camera"></i></a>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                         <div class="three fields">
                           <div class="field"></div>
                           <div class="field">
                              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="ui fluid mini positive button">
                                Signup &nbsp;<i class="icon user"></i>
                              </button>
                           </div>
                           <div class="field"></div>
                         </div>
                          <div>
                            <?php
                              if(!empty($errorMsg)){
                                echo $errorMsg;
                              }
                            ?>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

HERE IS MY PHP FUNCTION WHICH RECEIVES THE `FILE['image']` A PARAMETER.

```
    <?php
function uploadFile($file){
  $newName;
  if(isset($file)){    
    $file_name = $file['name'];
    $file_tmp_loc = $file['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $file['size'];
    $file_error = $file['error'];

    $ext  = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
    $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif');

    if(in_array($allowed, $allowed)){
      if($file_error == 0){
        if($file_size > 3000000){
          $file_name_new = uniqid('',true).".".$ext;
          $destination = '../images/users/';
          $destination = $destination.$file_name_new;

          if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_loc, $destination)){
            $newName = $destination;
          }else{
            echo "<h1>Failed to move uploaded file</h1>";
          }
        }
      }else{
        echo "file upload failed. ".$file['error'];
      }
    }else{
      echo "Type not allowed!";    }
  }
}
   return $newName;  
?>
```

In my other PHP script, I am calling the function like this:

```
<?php
$fileName = uploadFile($_FILE['image']);
?>
```

an then stores the returned new name as its reference in the MySQL DB

Comment: And your specific question is _what_? What is the issue with that code? What exactly is not working as expected? What actually happens if you use it? Do you get an error? Which? What does your http servers error log file contain?

Comment: Stop trying to solve all your problems at the same time. Separate out the different bits of functionality and get them working in isolation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the $_FILES when you receiving file and in first array mean $_FILES['the file name which you have mentioned in Input files by Name like name='abc' '] and second array is all about file name, size, error,location. you can also see this by using print_r($_FILES['image']);

```
<input type="file" style="display: none;" id="pic" name="image"/>

        $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $file_tmp_loc = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
        $file_error = $_FILES['image']['error'];
```

So correct it!

Cheer you!

Answer (score 0):

As I have seen your input field name for the file is `image`. So you should pass a file object to called function `$_FILES`.

```
<?php
$fileName = uploadFile($_FILES);
?>
```

See your input file field

```
<input type="file" style="display: none;" id="pic" name="image"/>
```

and change code in where you are trying to upload the image as:

```
$file_name = $file['image']['name'];
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is running code.

```
$image_file = $_FILES['school_logo']['name'];
$tmp=$_FILES["school_logo"]["tmp_name"];
$ext = pathinfo($image_file ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$folder="images/school_logo/";
$logos='logo'.'-'.uniqid(date('dmy')).rand().'.'.$ext;
$test=move_uploaded_file($tmp,$folder.$logos);
```

I hope this code is helpful for you.